# Best approach to handle dates on typescript interfaces from server

Tags: angular, typescript, class, interface

Following this question [Dates in a Typescript interface are actually strings when inspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925786/dates-in-a-typescript-interface-are-actually-strings-when-inspected)

I defined a typescript interface for a response I received from a server API call, which has a parameter Date. Since it comes as json and it is a string, further calls to that parameter work on the IDE but won't work on the browser since it really is a string.

I've solved it already using a new Date() when using that parameter but that defeats the purpose of having it as a Date in the first place.

I could change it to a Class instead of an interface, but is it a good enough reason to do it? And for big objects that's a lot of boilerplate...

I could parse that response on the service and convert it to Date? Or in an interceptor (any idea how?)?

```
export interface ResourceMovement {
  lastMovementDate?: Date;
}

// got this from the server
const movement: ResourceMovement;

// no error on IDE, but error on browser
const time = movement.lastMovementDate.getTime();
```

Mostly I am looking for ideas and a discussion of the most clean and reusable way to solve this!

Comment: JSON doesn't support dates, that's why they come as strings. You should use data transfer objects that have only the primitives supported by JSON and convert them after deserialization.

Comment: Interfaces are not transpiled hence final JavaScript knows nothing about them. If your dates are received from API as strings (in JSON response), you have to convert it into Date manually. One way to do this is by interceptor that will traverse the response and converts all string values that conform to date ISO format. Other way could be to define custom decorators for your model properties and implement parser for that.

Comment: could that interceptor _guess_ that I am expecting an interface with dates and convert that specific string only? and how would you approach the decorator option, which would mean I need to use a class instead of an interface, right?

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches can be considered.

The most common one would be to rely on timestamps. Timestamps are numbers, in MS, from Jan. 1st, 1970 on GMT+0. any language I am aware of can read a timestamp.

The second approach would be to use specific strings, such as UTC dates or ISO dates. Those are accepted formats that most of the languages can read, if not all. They contain the timezone, contrary to the timestamp.

The solution to use highly depends on your need : if you need the date to be set by the server, then a timestamp is the way to go. But if you want your users to set the date according to their locale, then you will need to use a string.

Now, to convert your dates into the required format, I would personally use a mapper in a dedicated utils/service.

The issue with an interceptor is that you can't really know which field is a date, since they aren't instances of Date, but strings/numbers.

You could probably use an interceptor with custom headers to determine which field to convert, but that's using a MOAB to kill a cockroach ...

Comment: yes we are using ISO dates and that's working fine. my problem is that I am defining a type as date, and then whenever I access it I need to call the new Date() on it. i agree that custom headers are a MOAB, but was hoping that javascript or typescript could have a nice solution to identify that I am receiving that Interface and convert that value to Date, on every request.

Comment: @talkshowhost an interface won't be able to determine that, but a class will definitely do. [Class-Transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) can be very helpful with that !

Comment: very interesting, didn't know this lib and will look into it! thanks